# What is the best practices in naming methods in php?

Tags: php, function, oop, methods

What is the best way to know what should your method name be when developing a web app? I know this is an easy question, but seriously what considerations and practices should I be doing in order to derive the best names possible for my methods?

Comment: It's not an easy question -- the two hardest things in computer science are naming things, cache invalidation, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: @MarkBaker ha ha

Comment: php-fig.org maybe a good suggestion

Comment: name the functions so you know what they do without reading function documention

Comment: You might get some insights from this lecture: https://vimeo.com/13702091